# Auto-save file on keypress

Tags: save

How can I automatically `:w` save a file after each keypress?

Devs who have used editors like PHPStorm know this is particularly handy so I was looking for a way to achieve the same with vim.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991638/how-to-auto-save-a-file-every-1-second-in-vim

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! @Zorzi perhaps we need to cite that Q&A? If you want to post the answer, by all means, go ahead (and, on the off-chance that you feel like you're getting rep from someone else's work, I think it's fine, but you can community-wiki to opt out of the rep)

Comment: In the todo list of vim there is this: [`:h 'autosave'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/todo.txt.html#%27autosave%27). When it's available that might be an interesting built-in solution rather than using autocommands.